# MKMapView Annotation Deselection Policy

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

`MKMapView` deselects annotations when the user taps the map itself, or when the user taps a different annotation. I've also noticed however that occasionally annotations can be deselected during panning or zooming operations. I'm keen to understand the precise rules governing this behaviour, and was wondering if anyone has any ideas. The documentation isn't helpful, and the only other thing I've found is a [post](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8021) from a discussion on a `MapBox` issue which states that *`MapKit` does a partial deselection based on velocity but never fully deselect* [sic]*. In a sense this is helpful, since it suggests that the speed at which the map is moved around plays a role, but it also muddies the waters somewhat by introducing the concept of partial selection - not something I've come across before.

Comment: Can you perhaps post an example project we can run and play with to see this spontaneous deselection in action? I've never seen this. Of course, if an annotation goes off the screen, it is destroyed (or at least its view is), so I'm not surprised if it loses its selected status. In general selection is not meant to be persistent; it's just a way of peeking at the callout (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a question about that Github comment about “partial deselection based on velocity”, you should just ask the author of that comment directly on Github.

Re documentation about the precise rules, I know of no such documentation. The `MKAnnotationView` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview) is somewhat vague, alluding to user toggling only:

> Additionally, annotation views support the concept of a selection state, which determines whether the view is unselected, selected, or selected and displaying a standard callout view. The user toggles between the selection states through interactions with the annotation view.

Personally, I’ve never seen any “velocity”-based deselection. And the notion of “partially deselecting” doesn’t make sense to me either.

Deselecting happens if (a) the user taps elsewhere; or (b) if the annotation view is offscreen and subsequently dequeued and reused for another annotation.